# Popup window to display result from php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to implement javascript to display result from php.

Basically, I have a login page. For fail login, instead of just echoing them with php, I want the result to be display in a popup.

I try to implement the alert box but looks like I miss something.

Successful login will be redirect to `logged.php` and will display the details of **UserName** and **LoginStatus**.

If the login failed, since I'm using stored procedure the `LoginStatus` will automatically displayed the error message of the fail operation.

Here's my full code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dqmuc87/)

This is my login page.

login.php

```
$stmt=odbc_exec($conn,"CALL UserLogin (".$_POST['UserId'].",'".$_POST['UserPwd']."','".$_POST['ModuleCd']."','".$_POST['SubModuleCd']."')");

if (!$stmt)
{
"Error : " . odbc_errormsg();
}

if (odbc_fetch_row($stmt))
{

$Username=odbc_result($stmt,"Username");
$LoginStatus=odbc_result($stmt,"LoginStatus");
}

/*Succesful Login*/
if ($LoginStatus==1)
{

$_SESSION["Username"]=$Username;
$_SESSION["LoginStatus"]=$LoginStatus;
header("Location: logged.php");
}

else

/*Fail Login*/
echo $Username=odbc_result($stmt,"Username");
echo $LoginStatus=odbc_result($stmt,"LoginStatus");
```

html :

```
<form method="post" name="login">
  <input type="text" name="UserId" value="">
  <input type="password" name="UserPwd" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
  </form>
```

javascript :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
     /*message of fail login*/
            function show_alert() {
                if (LoginStatus != 1) {
                    alert(LoginStatus);
                }
    
    
            </script>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: from where the LoginStatus came from?

Comment: You cant use php varibles in javascript directly

Comment: You should use AJAX with jQuery with your php code.

Comment: They are from the database that I work with. I'm using stored procedure btw. @SagarV .

Comment: This is my first time trying to work with javascript. Thanks for that :) @B.Desai .

Comment: Will look into it. Thanks @HarshBarach

Comment: check out the answer

Comment: you have to make ajax request with your server details from the function xhr in the code. So, either provide your page name, parameters, etc. or try to implement by your own

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form method="post" name="login">
  <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="">
  <input type="password" name="UserPwd" id="UserPwd" value="">
  <input type="button" onclick="xhr();" name="login" value="Login">
  </form>
```

```js
function xhr(){
  var un=document.getElementById('UserId').value;
  var pw=document.getElementById('UserPwd').value; 
  //assume that x is the XHR object
  x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open("POST","login.php",true);
  x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var params="UserId="+un+"&UserPwd="+pw;
  x.send(params);
  x.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200){
       checkLogin(x.responseText);
     }
  }
}
function checkLogin(x){
  if(x != 1)
    alert("Login failed");
  else
     window.location.href="logged.php";
}
```

The PHP server page should echo only "1" or ~1 (0 or something else). no other echo statement must be there in the PHP page

Comment: I'm kind of confuse since this is my first time trying. Could you please explain more of this?

Comment: sure. I need some details like the id of username and password field, the page you want to send the request to (The php server page name)

Comment: Updated answer to exactly fit your needs

Comment: They doesn't work. How can I set the `x` to be `LoginStatus` ? Since the login depends on value of the LoginStatus. @SagarV

Comment: x is on client side. Just replace the code in your javascript and form with this code.

Comment: Will notify you once I got the result :) @SagarV

Comment: Hey @SagarV . I just tried your solution and add a few more parameter for the login. The issue is even when I entered the right login credentials the popup keep coming out.

Comment: Paste your entire code in fiddle and then let me know. So i can check it. @Mint

Comment: Will look into it soon . currently working on another @Mint

Comment: @Mint , I added a new answer below. Please check it and if there is any error, just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to send data using Ajax to the PHP and get the answer back and show the popup message**

HTML :

```
<form id="login" action="#" method="POST">

            <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />

            <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />

            <button id="submit" > Submit </button>

</form>
```

JS : (U need jQuery library)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery("#login").submit(function(event)
{
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: jQuery("#login").serialize(),

        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == "failed")
            {
                alert("LoginStatus"); // If you want send the variable LoginStatus from PHP to JS, you have to get data back using Json !
            }
            else if(data == "success")
            {
                window.location.href = "logged.php";
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

PHP :

Use your PHP code and check whatever condition is true or false and echo it as "failed" or "success".

Comment: Thank you @Soheyl , I'll look into your code. Need some time since this is my first time to work with js

Comment: Hey @Soheyl . I kind of confuse by the variable `data` of **failed**  and  **success**  on the code. Instead of echoing my own error message. The error message is automatically called from the stored procedure when the `LoginStatus != 1` . What should I do to implement the `LoginStatus != 1` to the data instead of just `"failed"` and `"success"` ?

Comment: This is what I tried https://jsfiddle.net/mxnnn/qurLkom6/ . I can enter the logged page when the right credentials is entered. The problem is the echo of `failed` keep showing up on the form and no popup. @Shoeyl

Comment: If your LoginStatus is statistic, it's better to use this options I already told you, and you can replace your message in this part : alert("LoginStatus"); // you can add whatever you want here ! Bt if you want return the LoginStatus (if it's a dynamic), you have to use type as JSON and get data back from your PHP ! You can't get data back from PHP like your example ! @Mint

Comment: Good luck @Mint

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value of $LoginStatus from php instead of using redirection.
Also, `select` didn't need a value attribute like `<select value="">` is incorrect.
Now check this answer

```js
function xhr(){
  var un=document.getElementById('UserId').value;
  var pw=document.getElementById('UserPwd').value; 
  var md=document.getElementById('ModuleCd').value; 
  var smd=document.getElementById('SubModuleCd').value; 
  //assume that x is the XHR object
  x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open("POST","login.php",true);
  x.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var params="UserId="+un+"&UserPwd="+pw+"&ModuleCd="+md+"&SubModuleCd="+smd;
  x.send(params);
  x.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200){
       console.log(x.responseText);
       checkLogin(x.responseText);
     }
  }
}
function checkLogin(x){
  if(x != 1)
    alert("Login failed");
  else
     window.location.href="logged.php";
}
```

```css
<?php
session_start();

$conn=odbc_connect("DSN", " ", " ");

if (!$conn)
{
  echo "Connection Failed : " . $conn;
  exit(0);
}

$stmt=odbc_exec($conn,"CALL UserLogin (".$_POST['UserId'].",'".$_POST['UserPwd']."','".$_POST['ModuleCd']."','".$_POST['SubModuleCd']."')");

if (!$stmt)
    {
    echo "Error : " . odbc_errormsg();
    }

if (odbc_fetch_row($stmt))
{

$Username=odbc_result($stmt,"Username");
$LoginStatus=odbc_result($stmt,"LoginStatus");
}

if($LoginStatus==1)
{

$_SESSION["Username"]=$Username;
$_SESSION["LoginStatus"]=$LoginStatus;
echo $LoginStatus;
}
/*
else

echo $Username=odbc_result($stmt,"Username");
echo $LoginStatus=odbc_result($stmt,"LoginStatus");
*/

?>
```

```html
<form method="post" name="login">

<input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="">
<input type="password" name="UserPwd" id="UserPwd" value="">
<select name="ModuleCd" id="ModuleCd">
<option value="">Module</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
</select>
<select name="SubModuleCd" id="SubModuleCd">
<option value="">SubModule</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="xhr();" name="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: I think the script is not functioning. The `$LoginStatus` doesn't return any value to the script. I've a question, with `x != 1` , how is the `$LoginStatus == 1` is define? @SagarV

Comment: I added a console.log inside ajax request. now after submiting, check your console(f12) what is the result.
or make a screenshot and add it

Comment: Both right and wrong credentials result in the popup. The console doesn't return any value btw. The console.log is not affected by the $Username? What if I added one more parameter with integer value and return them as result. What will happened to the console.log? @SagarV

Comment: What is printed in console?

Comment: @Mint , click ok for the alert box and then take screenshot. I can't see console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135344/discussion-between-mint-and-sagar-v).