# Execute a while loop every second

Tags: php

I got this while loop that is displaying as you can see a username and a message which the user types... But after the message has been typed the user have to reload my page to see it. Is there a way to make the while loop execute while im on the site to keep it constantly updated?! like setting it to execute every second or something?

```
        <?php 
include "connect.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages";
$result = $con->query($query);

if($result){

            while($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
            {
                echo "<ul id = 'rutor'>";
                echo '<li class = "userlada">'.$row->username. "</li>";
                echo '<li class = "usertext">'.$row->message. "</li>";
                echo "</ul>";
            }

}
?>
```

I'm not the brigetest on php so any help would be great!:)

Comment: Checkout keyword: Ajax https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX by pure PHP it's not possible...

Comment: javascript ajax. You will need to send the last ID that you are currently showing to server, server will have to see if there are new ID's and send you new ones. You will need to append those results to your stuff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106812/popup-window-to-display-result-from-php-with-javascript/42107302#42107302

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if it's not a "search type thing" you could use that query(which fetches all the data), and through jQuery or JS show data every 1 second. If you want to fetch data as the user types something..(generally if you don't want to refresh page but making a requests) then yes use AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

PHP is server-side, so if you start waiting and looping there, you'll just make the browser wait for it to be done.

For this you need to look into Javascript.

Comment: So i have to fetch the object and loop with javascript to make this work?

Comment: Yes. Simple way could be to use [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) together with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Comment: you dont have to send the ajax in a loop. Calling it when the message changes will be enough. `<input type="text" onchange="refreshUserList()">` in the function refreshUserList() you would do the ajax call.

Comment: That's a good option, yes. Although it wouldn't work if messages could also be entered by others (thinking chat type messaging here).

Comment: I tried what you said with the jquery.load and to setTimeout and it worked great, thanks alot! @Svish

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is going to be a very unpopular opinion, with practically no useful application, and horrible thing to do  since it WILL cause your server to crash if over 200 people simply open your page. But...

**Yes**, It can be done quite easily with iframe. Here is how:

Create a page that servers nothing but those messages. Lets call it 'bad_practice.php'. What you want to do is make your code look like this:

```
ob_implicit_flush();//makes php NOT buffer and send data straight to screen
$last_id=1234;//or keep track of it.

while(true)
{
$new_query=DB::Query("select * from messages where id> :last_id",array(":last_id"=>$last_id));
while($row=$new_query->fetch())
{
                echo "<ul id = 'rutor'>";
                echo '<li class = "userlada">'.$row->username. "</li>";
                echo '<li class = "usertext">'.$row->message. "</li>";
                echo "</ul>";
                $last_id=$row['id'];
}

sleep(1);
}
```

after that you will need to create an iframe on your main page

```
<iframe src="bad_practice.php">
```

And you should have a working constantly refreshing list of things.

Comment: That's horrible, but would indeed probably "work" 